# C# Populating Array Elements with For Loops

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, for-loop

It may be the late hour of the night, it may be the ire of the gods. I've reread what should be as simple as can be countless times. Could some kind soul help me out here, what is going on?

Goal is to have a random quote appear on screen pulled from a prepared list of quotes I have on-hand; which can be refreshed by the click of a button to display a new quote. Working in Unity for context.

At first I intended to populate the array by pulling them straight from the text file I have... a few hours later I came to the decision to hand type them all in. I thought to make it easier on myself by creating a for loop to avoid keying in each individual index number, and it would appear that's where my progress has ceased.

At runtime **quotes[x]** produces only the last index entry shown below; it produces the exact same result even if I specify *Debug.Log* to print indexes **[0]**, **[1]**, **[2]** so on and so forth. I tested and verified that **int x** is working as intended and actually generating random numbers. If I remove the *for loop* and manually key in all the index numbers that appears to work as well.

What is it about this for loop that's causing all indexes to hold the same value? I know I can work around it, but I'd rather understand why it's not producing the expected result.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Quotes : MonoBehaviour
{        
    public void GenerateQuote()
    {      
        string[] quotes = new string[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < quotes.Length; i++)
            {
                quotes[i] = "It worked! 0";
                quotes[i] = "It worked! 1";
                quotes[i] = "It worked! 2";
                quotes[i] = "It worked! 3";
                quotes[i] = "It worked! 4";
                quotes[i] = "It worked! 5";
                quotes[i] = "It worked! 6";
                quotes[i] = "It worked! 7";
                quotes[i] = "It worked! 8";
                quotes[i] = "For loop has failed and will be taken out back for its insolence";
            }     

        int x = Random.Range(0,9);
        Debug.Log(quotes[x]);

    }
}
```

[Console Debug.Log writes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhdmA.png)
[Method ran from button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qenu.png)

Tried to employ the Rubber Ducky troubleshooting method, I suppose I expected it to work (bold of me), failed miserably

Comment: Instead of the loop, you need to write `quotes[0] = "It worked! 0";` `quotes[1] = "It worked! 1";` etc.

Comment: The last statement in your loop's body is `quote[i] = "for loop has failed ..."` Thus, in every iteration of the loop (ie for every `i`) you are setting `quote[i]` to that value. Ie all entries of the quote array are `"for loop has failed ..."`

Comment: Thanks for posting a funnily worded question :) This site can be so serious sometimes. Did the answers solve the issue for you?

Comment: @Absinthe Amazing what a full night's (day's in my case) sleep can do. Yes, I see clearly now where I errored in my logic. Each iteration of the *for loop* was assigning every element the same index number. So by the last iteration every element was the same as the last. New rule, don't code past 9pm!

Comment: Know what that's like, it's so common for programmers. Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason why your code is not working properly is becasuse thats not the proper way to use a for loop, you are changing each index value with all quates at the same time, so first its value is "It worked! 0" but the is changed to "It worked! 1" so I will fix it like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Quotes : MonoBehaviour
{        
    public void GenerateQuote()
    {      
        string[] quotes = new string[10];
        quotes[0] = "It worked! 0";
        quotes[1] = "It worked! 1";
        quotes[2] = "It worked! 2";
        quotes[3] = "It worked! 3";
        quotes[4] = "It worked! 4";
        quotes[5] = "It worked! 5";
        quotes[6] = "It worked! 6";
        quotes[7] = "It worked! 7";
        quotes[8] = "It worked! 8";
        quotes[9] = "For loop has failed";

        int x = Random.Range(0,9);
        Debug.Log(quotes[x]);

    }
}
```

If you want to make it manual but it will be better if you read the text file and with a for loop yo populate the quotes variables with a for loop.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that reading from the text file was the correct way to go about this

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting the same index value in your for loop. Just write

```
for(int i = 0; i < quotes.Length; i++)
        {
            quotes[i] = $"sample text for index {i}";
        }
```

The night thing definitely got to you.

Comment: It appears that my brain conceptually mixed the two approaches of automatic and manual index population. You're right, sleep deprivation is a hell of a drug!